# Multiple SUM's in one SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `DS.UnitPrice` and `Ord.Qty` that I need to multiply. Then take the sum of that and add up each of those if there is multiple `LineTotal`'s.

From there, take the subtotal and multiply it by `1.1` (tax
of 10%) and get the orders total.

I had issues with `SubTotal`, but got it to work. But `TotalPrice` still gives me `0`, no matter what I do.

This is my query:

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(DS.UnitPrice*Ord.Qty) AS LineTotal,
       SUM(LineTotal) AS SubTotal,
       SUM(SubTotal*1.1) AS TotalPrice
 FROM (Orders Ord, Donuts DS, Customers Cust)
    LEFT JOIN Customers ON (Cust.CustID = Ord.OrderID)
    LEFT JOIN Donuts ON (DS.DonutID = Ord.DonutID)
```

Comment: Do you want to have each unit's caculated price along with subtotal? In your query, LineTotal and SubTotal will be same thing

Comment: Why mix old comma separated, implicit joins with moder LEFT JOIN syntax? Very confusing. Why are Customers and Donuts included twice?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are referring to a column alias `subtotal` in the definition of total.  And, your `JOIN` conditions are all wrong.

If you want the totals per order:

```
SELECT Ord.OrderId,
       SUM(DS.UnitPrice * Ord.Qty) AS SubTotal,
       SUM(DS.UnitPrice * Ord.Qty * 1.1) AS TotalPrice
FROM Orders Ord JOIN
     Customers Cust
     ON Cust.CustID = Ord.OrderID JOIN
     Donuts DS
     ON DS.DonutID = Ord.DonutID
GROUP BY Ord.OrderId;
```

If you want the totals for all orders:

```
SELECT SUM(DS.UnitPrice * Ord.Qty) AS SubTotal,
       SUM(DS.UnitPrice * Ord.Qty * 1.1) AS TotalPrice
FROM Orders Ord JOIN
     Customers Cust
     ON Cust.CustID = Ord.OrderID JOIN
     Donuts DS
     ON DS.DonutID = Ord.DonutID;
```

Comment: This one and the first one answer at the top help a lot, I just need to figure out now where to put the needed select * for all the info about the order, the customer and such

Answer (score 0):

you can do this one :

```
SELECT *, SUM(DS.UnitPrice*Ord.Qty) as LineTotal ,SUM(LineTotal) as SubTotal,SUM(SubTotal*1.1) as TotalPrice
FROM (Orders Ord, Donuts DS, Customers Cust)
LEFT JOIN Customers ON (Cust.CustID = Ord.OrderID)
LEFT JOIN Donuts ON (DS.DonutID = Ord.DonutID)
```

Comment: I got everything to swho now along with totals showing correctly, thank you so much all!


`SELECT *,
       SUM(DS.UnitPrice * Ord.Qty) AS LineTotal,
       SUM(LineTotal) AS SubTotal,
       SUM(DS.UnitPrice * Ord.Qty * 1.1) AS TotalPrice
FROM Orders Ord JOIN
     Customers Cust
     ON Cust.CustID = Ord.OrderID JOIN
     Donuts DS
     ON DS.DonutID = Ord.DonutID
GROUP BY Ord.OrderId`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if the subtotal or total needs to be grouped by orders, but here is the query. You may remove the GROUP BY clause if not required to group:

### Grouped By OrderId

```
SELECT 
    SUM(subtotal) total,
    SUM(subtotal) * 1.1 totalwithtax,
    SUM(subtotalquantity) totalqty
FROM
    (SELECT 
        SUM(linetotal) subtotal,
            SUM(quantity) subtotalquantity,
            orderid
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        DS.UnitPrice * Ord.Qty linetotal,
            Ord.Qty quantity,
            ord.OrderID,
            ds.DonutID
    FROM
        Donuts DS
    JOIN Orders Ord ON (DS.DonutID = Ord.DonutID)
    ORDER BY orderid) linetotaltab
    GROUP BY orderid) totaltable
GROUP BY orderid
```